# Can you bind an object containing a Dictionary Property to a dropdownlist?

Tags: asp.net, data-binding

For example, I have an instance of the following class declaration:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name = "";
    public Dictionary<string, string> Properties = new Dictionary<string, string>();
}
```

And I have a list of person that I wish to bind to an Asp.NET drop down list.

```
List<Person> people = new List<Person>();
//fill the list etc..

//bind to the drop down list
ddlPeople.DataSource = people;
ddlPeople.DataTextField = "Name";
ddlPeople.DataTextField = "Properties['Age']"; //this is what I would like!
```

Age is always present.  I do not have control of the person class.  Does anyone know if what I am trying to do is achievable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you can not do that.

I guess I would go for :

```
ddlPeople.Items.Clear();
ddlPeople.Items.AddRange(people.Select(p => new ListItem(p.Name, p.Properties["Age"])).ToArray());
```

But I am not sure it is the point of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could just create a read-only property on your person class?

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name = "";
    public Dictionary<string, string> Properties = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    public int Age
    {
        get
        {
            // ... code to handle situations where Properties
            //     is null or does not contain key
            return (int)this.Properties["Age"];
        }
    }
}
```

I believe the kind of binding you're seeking is possible in WPF, but I don't think I've ever seen it done in ASP.NET.